# SQL Query List Those that are higher than average

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 tables in the following format:

- employee (employeeID, EmployeeName, DepartmentID)
- departments (DepartmentID, DeptName)

How many employees there are who work in each of the departments that have more employees than the average number of employees in a department.

im looking to the results in the following format:

```
Dept Name   | Num of Emp
engineering | 10
science     | 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since an employee can be in only one department, the average number of employees is just the total # of employees over the total number of departments. So how about:

```
SELECT    dept.name, COUNT(emp.id) AS employeeCount
FROM         emp INNER JOIN dept ON emp.deptId = dept.id
GROUP BY dept.name
HAVING      (COUNT(emp.id) >
(SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM emp) /
(SELECT     COUNT(*) FROM dept))
```

Comment: This of course assumes that the departments with `0` employees contribute to the average.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Don't most averages include the zeros in the population?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  deptName, cnt
FROM    (
        SELECT  departmentID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM    employee
        GROUP BY
                departmentID
        HAVING  COUNT(*) >=
                (
                SELECT  AVG(cnt)
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  COUNT(*) AS cnt
                        FROM    employee
                        GROUP BY
                                departmentID
                        )
                )
        ) e
JOIN    departments d
ON      d.departmentID = e.departmentID
```

In `Oracle`, you can use analytic functions which are more elegant:

```
SELECT  DeptName, cnt
FROM    (
        SELECT  q.*, AVG(cnt) OVER() AS acnt
        FROM    (
                SELECT  departmentID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
                FROM    employee
                GROUP BY
                        departmentID
                ) q
        ) e
JOIN    departments d
ON      d.departmentID = e.departmentID
WHERE   cnt >= acnt
```

Comment: don't you need a GROUP BY on the outer most SELECT so the HAVING knows what to filter?

Comment: Sure I do, cut it instead of copying to the outer query :)

Comment: i cant get either to work... im running this in oracle.
where is the reference to the department name in the department table?